# creating a continuous function that takes negative values MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For a lab homework I am trying to create a continuous signal whose range will be from -20 to 50. However, MATLAB does not allow me to do so as it is saying that "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values".

For example,

```
t =-20:+0.01:49.99;
y(t) = cos(t);
```

I do not want to do shifting. Is there any other way?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `y(t)` the parens are indexing into the array `y`, whereas for `cos(t)` the parens are passing in an argument. They are not same thing, and not the same as you'd write down an equation.
You'll need to read up on MATLAB arrays (the `y`) and MATLAB functions (the `cos`) to understand this.

Comment: To summarise @Justin's comment, you need to use `y = cos(t)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make a continuous signal, You have to create a function handle. Apart from the negative indices, your example is discrete. Here is an example:

```
y = @(t)cosinFun(t);

function y = cosinFun(t)
if (t>-20||t<50)
    y = cos(t);
else
    y = 0;
end
end
```

Where y(t) is cos(t) at-20<t<50, and zero for other values.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP question, and the statement about needing a function handle for a continuous signal is at best confusing and at worst wrong.
But crucially this function above will only work with scalar inputs, not with array inputs. Sorry to say it's not a correct answer.
Better look at @Wolfie's comment!

Comment: Well, I agree with the confusion since there are lots of grey areas in the question, but @Wolfie's comment will lead to a discrete signal either, and it seems kind of obvious to do. My answer is based on the assumption that the author needs to use the continuous signal inside a user-defined function or algorithms like convex optimization.